# Integrity constraint violation error magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4.3

I am getting this error:
main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'last_visit_at' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `customer_visitor` (`customer_id`, `session_id`, `last_visit_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [] []

please guide me on how to solve this.

Comment: try setting nullable as true

Comment: thank u but when i run setup upgrade its again set to null is there any permenant solution

Comment: do this in db_Schema file from where you are adding this field